# Filter on first element of array in Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ransack

I currently have a two rails models: `Parts` and `PartStatuses`. A `Part` has_many `PartStatuses` and the latest `PartStatus` is the current status of the part.

I want to have a ransack filter to only show `Active` statuses. `Active` is the value of the `status_name` attribute on the `PartStatus` model.

Ideally I would want a filter such as "part_part_statuses_status_last_eq" => "active".

Comment: I would solve it in two stages: 1) Prepare a scope on Part that fetches all the active ones (by joining with part_statuses and checking the status of the latest). 2) Have Ransack search your scope (https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#using-scopesclass-methods)

Comment: Unfortunately I need the active status to be the latest status so it's not simply enough to check that there is an active status for that part